Is Stack Exchange experiencing something like another Eternal September?
In a recent post,
Steve can help ♦ commented:

We've had a number of low quality questions remaining open for weeks without VTC, so it'll take a bit of work for all of us to find the right balance.

I've been meaning to ask this question for a while now, and this comment confirms my observation.
It feels like I've submitted more votes-to-close in the last few months than in all my previous years combined.
And it's not because I disagree with the content of the posts; it's because the posts are fundamentally bad (either because they are far too complicated and difficult to understand or because they don't follow standards).
And that's not only on this site.
Is Stack Exchange experiencing something like another Eternal September (perhaps from Gen Z becoming adults), or what?

My own recent meta post on brevity was somewhat inspired by related reasons.
Our site specifically seems to be getting more new users. Some new users are new to hermeneutics altogether, others are experienced in hermeneutics, but are new to Stack Exchange's desire for concise brevity. Our way of posting is unique in being a combination of newswriting and encyclopedic writing. Users will face something new regardless of where they arrived from.
It is probably just a lot of new users, and it's probably a healthy sign.

As a new user, I haven't noticed any particular house style here. And although I found posts about what makes a good question, it didn't explain the standards-as-practised.
I shan't comment the OP with "What does Eternal September mean? Is there a reference for that? Can you link to people who use that term?" - but that's more what I expect when I post a question than an answer.
That's from 2 weeks of solid use, which is neither much or nothing.
I'm here because internet searches for literary-grammatical or technical-theological interpretation of bible passages return mush.
There is "Dying Internet" and "Enrubbishification" - but it's been going on longer and affects the physical books as well. Where I am the second-hand bookshops can't tell Max Margolis from Justin Welby.
So that's probably healthy for site traffic. But perhaps less can be assumed than before about who's arriving.

Eternal September — Today is the 11,302ⁿᵈ day of September 1993. Newsgroups used to be used by universities following "netiquette" or according to "Emily Postnews". Even with flame-wars, we still got along very well. But once a year, universities would get a bunch of new users who wouldn't know the rules and post "me too" and add signature files, and generally make a mess of things. They would get jumped on, and learn, and soon be themselves yelling at others that did things wrong. Then came AOL, and that September hasn't ended yet.

I just responded to a long post, it applies to some of your questions too.
¶ Long questions are inherently bad.
Top questions on this site are under 100 words long, while your recent "Does hermeneutics categorize flaws …?", has over 1200 words, all of which, as I said in a comment, could be replaced by: "Do the merits of an exegesis that failed to use some evidence depend upon whether the omission was deliberate or accidental?".

And don't think I'm picking on you (if you do, please say so). You are just a good example of the situation (postings that are far far too long, and postings where the question isn't at all obvious), both because you respond to comments and because you posted here.

that was all fine - for me there seemed to be formulas to be complied with, a need for the question to have arisen from a bible text, a prohibition on propositional logic/notation, the workings to be shown, I thought perhaps some answer-hero culture. We move on, I'll try and make its follow-up shorter

In case you haven't seen them, way down at the bottom left of most pages are two links:
Tour - Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange
and Help Center.
The first gives a too-brief overview; the second has links to various questions that provide a little more detail.
¶ All the Stack Exchange sites deliberately have a steep learning curve, and users are supposed to see learning and using the system as if it were a game.
(It's not how I'd run the world, but I'm hardly the one in charge.)
